# How to get the calendar view to select the period of time in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

How can I get the calendar view by clicking on the input box in the html page?
I need a page to let the user select the period of time to generate a file. So, how could I achieve this?

Please provide me the sample html & JS code

Comment: Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to try by yourself than ask queries if you not could solve.

Answer (score 1):

Google is a useful tool.

```
<input type="date">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date